# Matplotlib multiline axis text with different font size

Tags: python, matplotlib, scientific-computing

How can I change the font size within the same matplotlib's y axis text. In the code below how put the unit (i.e., m4 kg-1 s-1) in smaller font below the name of the variable (i.e., Resistance)?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1], [1])
plt.ylabel('Total resistance\nm$^{4}$ kg$^{-1}$s$^{-1}$', multialignment='center', fontsize=12, labelpad=5)
```

Comment: there is _way_ too much code here.  Please reduce this to the minimum amount of code needed to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: thanks for the comment @tcaswell I've greatly reduced the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about use `_`:

```
pl.plot([1], [1])
pl.ylabel('Total resistance\n$\\regular_{{m}^{4} kg^{-1}s^{-1}}$', fontsize=20)
```

Here is the output:

[image]